# How to break superposed objects into pieces on inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, shapes

I'm manipulating a vector in which I have six circles superposed like in a Venn Diagram. I want to easily break them into pieces by color. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Is it vector? what's the file format? We need more info to be able to help you with this.

Comment: Thank you, Luciano. I'll edit my answer to provide the info.

Comment: Just for some added searchability, this would be done in Illustrator using "flatten transparency".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not going to keep the colors, but it makes the process faster:

- Make a copy of the circles, and put it aside (for the colors). Keep it untouched.
- Duplicate the circles, combine the duplicated ones.
- Union the other circles
- Put the unioned circles to the bottom
- Do Path -> Division with both the unioned and the combined circles selected

Now you've got the pieces.

Next you can go about re-assigning the colors with the dropper tool (it may be useful to add a stroke to the pieces temporarily). Tab through the objects (I mean the tab key), and click on the corresponding color of your 'backup copy' with the dropper tool.

Another (faster, but less exact) way would be to: Make a bitmap copy (Edit > Bitmap copy), and then to do a trace of it, with the correct amount of colors, via Path > Trace bitmap.

Another inexact option would be to use the paint bucket tool to fill the differently colored fields.